# Why can't votes be changed after making them?

Tags: discussion, voting

After I up- or down-vote something/someone, I notice that I can't later change my mind. Why is this? I've certainly had reason to have a change of heart!

Comment: Maybe this is considered an abuse of the voting system, but one can change votes after the relevant post has been edited (or, in case of a question, retagged). And you have the reputation to edit other people's posts.

Comment: @lockstep: I'd count editing a post to change one's vote an abuse: it can cause the post to be CWified.  Better to ask the poster if they wouldn't mind editing their own post.

Comment: I regret that in one very maladroit moment I gave my first and only downvote by accidently clicking in the wrong (very tiny) pixel on my laptop screen. Furious reclicking did nothing to improve the situation. I rather like the way, for example, reddit.com provides the means for extricating yourself from this situation if you like. Clicking the reverse direction nullifies the first vote rather than recording a vote in the opposite direction. Sadly, I can only apologise to the person I very accidently demeaned.

Comment: @Geoffrey: You can reverse a mistaken vote for a short time after you cast it, by clicking again on the now lit arrow.  After doing this, you can't vote at all until the post is edited.

Comment: Thanks Charles, it seemed to work that way after my reclicking following my mistake. I wasn't left feeling too sure about that tho, since I was still awarded a -1 penalty (I think, although I could really be confused). I put the -1 down to a special SE maladroitness tax.

Comment: I can certainly see why one can't retract an upvote (except in the first few minutes), but it does seem like it would be best if one could retract a downvote or a "neutral" vote (which I seem to recall having accidentally locked in a few times on SO by retracting an up- or down- vote)...

Comment: @Geoffrey: you can audit your rep at the URL http://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation

Answer (score 8):

According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61431/163868
this is to prevent vote gaming. You can however change a vote after the post in question has been edited.

Comment: What is "vote gaming"?

Comment: @User17670 See the third definition in http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaming#Noun